# I cant type in terminal, as user input during code run

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I can't type in terminal when prompted for user input. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import * as readLine from 'readline'

const rl = readLine.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
})

rl.question('Enter your choice..: ', (answer) => {
     console.log(answer)
})
```

Im running it through console by `npm run main` with the following scripts in package.json:

```
"premain": "rimraf dist && tsc",
"main": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"node dist/index.js\""
```

I've tried:

- Adding `"code-runner.runInTerminal": true` to settings.json
- Enabling Legacy Terminal

Comment: For me it works if you just open the app directly using `node yourapp.js` (you will need to put `"type": "module",` in package.json. If you want to use `npm run dev` you have to add a `dev` script to package.json: `"scripts": { "dev": "node app.js"}`

Comment: @Kokodoko Thanks, command node actually let me write in console.
I use `npm run main` with the following scripts added in package.json :
`"premain": "rimraf dist && tsc",`
`"main": "concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"node dist/index.js\""`
Please propose your comment as a solution, in case someone in the future has the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it works if you just open the app directly using

```
node yourapp.js
```

you will need to put `"type": "module"` in package.json.

If you want to use `npm run dev` you have to add a dev script to package.json:

```
"scripts": { "dev": "node app.js"}
```